# Structure not holding value after assignment in C. No Value is displayed when I try to print

Tags: c

I am trying to assign values to some structures so that I can use those values later again in my code but I can't seem to get the structures to hold their values. printing the values inside the createReverseCircle() function works but anything outside the function does not. Am I incorrectly assigning the values?

```
struct queue
{
    struct soldier *front;
    struct soldier *back;
    char groundName[50];
    int *k;
    int *th;
};

int main()
{

    struct queue *theQueues = (struct queue *)malloc(sizeof(struct queue) * N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        init(&theQueues[i]);
    }

    createReverseCircle(&theQueues[0], 10, "Test Ground", 3, 2);

    //These print statements print nothing or give me an error
    printf("%s", theQueues[0].groundName); 
    printf("%d", theQueues[0].k);


void createReverseCircle(struct queue *q, int numOfSoldiers, char groundName[50], int k, int th)
{
    strcpy(q->groundName, groundName);
    q->k = &k;
    q->th = &th;

    for (int j = numOfSoldiers; j >= 1; j--)
    {
        enqueue(q, createSolider(j));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Your program isn't complete, but at the very least, these lines:

```
q->k = &k;
q->th = &th;
```

set fields in your structure as pointers to values on the stack - after `createReverseCircle` returns, dereferencing these pointers causes undefined behaviour.